# How resistant is the iPhone encryption against brute-force attacks?

Tags: encryption, brute-force, iphone

I just read the following paragraph in an [article from the New York Times about Apple encrypting iPhones by default](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/09/27/technology/iphone-locks-out-the-nsa-signaling-a-post-snowden-era-.html?google_editors_picks=true&_r=0)):

> Breaking the code, according to an Apple technical guide, could take “more than 5 1/2 years to try all combinations of a six-character alphanumeric passcode with lowercase letters and numbers.” (Computer security experts question that figure, because Apple does not fully realize how quickly the N.S.A. supercomputers can crack codes.)

From all the advice about encryption I've hear, how important pass phrases are, six digit passwords seem far too insecure to me in this scenario. From what I understand, an attacker that has posession of the phone could try out different passwords very quickly and in parallel.

Is there any reliable estimate on how much it would take (in time and hardware) for a brute-force attack against an iPhone with the given parameters for possible passwords?

Comment: "Computer security experts" don't add their name to this, because they would make themselves a laughing stock. Apple's trick here is to make sure that a passcode can only be checked on the phone storing the data; NSA's supercomputers would have to crack full 256 bit encryption.

Comment: It takes approximately 80ms to derive the encryption key from the user passcode. This effectively limits brute-force attacks to 80ms per attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple has quite a comprehensive [whitepaper](https://www.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security_Feb14.pdf) on iOS security.

According to the whitepaper:

> Every time a file on the data partition is created, Data Protection creates a new 256-bit 
>   key (the “per-file” key) and gives it to the hardware AES engine

Assuming an attacker had a file and nothing else then this would be quite secure.

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack):

> 50 supercomputers that could check a billion billion (1018) AES keys
>   per second (if such a device could ever be made) would, in theory,
>   require about 3×1051 years to exhaust the 256-bit key space.

However:

> The per-file key is wrapped with one of several class keys [...] The 
>   class key is protected with the hardware UID and, for some classes, the user’s passcode.

And

> To obtain the actual key, an attacker would have to mount a highly sophisticated 
>   and expensive physical attack against the processor’s silicon.

So if you *could* extract the hardware UID you may be able to then brute force it on the passcode alone. I suspect this would be a significant challenge even for the NSA though and they're probably resort to a [wrench](http://xkcd.com/538/) instead.

An attacker would also have to be careful if trying any form of online (as in entering the password while the device is powered on) attack because it's possible to set a policy whereby the phone is erased after 10 failed attempts.

> The "Erase all content and settings" option in Settings obliterates
>   all the keys in Effaceable  Storage, rendering all user data on the
>   device cryptographically inaccessible.

Basically it erases the encryption key for all the files, so then you'd be back to trying to brute force a 256 bit AES key.

Overall I'd say the iPhone is pretty secure considering how difficult it is to secure a device when an attacker can physically access it. Having said that, an iPhone is basically a black box so caveat emptor. There's still the possibility for bugs and vulnerabilities (such as say a weak RNG) or back doors.

When your adversary is someone such as the NSA you also can't discount the possibility of them compelling Apple to sign compromised firmware then [physically intercepting](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/05/cisco-ceo-to-obama-dont-let-nsa-intercept-and-hack-our-gear/) the device before it's delivered.

Comment: Surprised this Q&A isn't more viewed/upvoted, given recent events.